# Live preview of customizable HTML Template

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm building an app where the user can apply a base template and is able to modify only a part of this template.

Each template contains a base html and a customizable html part which is included somewhere in the base template.

my template object :

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Template name',
    preview: 'http://lorempixel.com/200/180/',

    template: {

        desktopTemplate: {

            html: '<div> Base html template </div>',

            modifiableHtml: '<div> modifiable html part </div>'

            css: ''

        },

    }

}
```

Each template is different so the customizable part is not always displayed at the same place ( schema http://image.prntscr.com/image/0984fdbf945b47c39eb2330230520e25.png )

I'm trying to do a live preview of the user customization but i'm still new to vue and i don't really find a way to do that.

how can i make this kind of component ? is it even possible in vue ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how this can work:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        modifiedHtml: ''
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-html="modifiedHtml"></div>
    <textarea cols="30" rows="10" v-model="modifiedHtml"></textarea>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Another example using a component to build this:

```js
Vue.component('desktop-template', {
  props: ['parentHtml'],
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Base html template</p>
      <div v-html="parentHtml"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  data () {
    return {
      css: '',  
    }
  },
})
              
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        modifiedHtml: ''
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <desktop-template :parent-html="modifiedHtml"></desktop-template>
    <textarea cols="30" rows="10" v-model="modifiedHtml"></textarea>
</div>
```

All you need to do is use the template of either the component or the root app (both methods now shown) to create what you are doing with `desktopTemplate.html`, doing so then makes that param redundant.

Comment: yes already know about v-html but this is not the solution here, desktopTemplate.modifiableHtml should be inside desktopTemplate.html

Comment: in vue you don't need `desktopTemplate.html` as a param as that is the html content you'll render as the components template. I'll update the answer to show this

Comment: Did that help clarify things - show you how this could work?